# How do I specify a parameter type by some quality of the parameter rather than its exact type?

Tags: c++, typing

So I have a function in C++ as follows:

```cpp
void print_vec(std::vector<int> v) {
  for (int i: v) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Which works and all, but is only applicable to int vectors. I want something like

```cpp
void print_iter(Iterable<CanDoCout> iterable) {
  for (auto i: iterable) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

How do I implement `print_iter`? Or how can I find out how to implement generic functions like this?

Comment: please don't add "SOLVED" to your question. Accepting an answer is the way to indicate that your quesiton is solved.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Really, there are textbooks covering C++20 concepts already? That would be surprising.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for are [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates):

```
template <class T>
void print_iter(const T& iterable) {
  for (const auto& i: iterable) {
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

You can go one step further and use [concepts](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) or [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to restrict your template to only types that accept the operations you apply.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Is it possible to restrict the type of the template to just types that support cout (like in Haskell you can restrict types to `Show`), or should I just let it throw an error?

Comment: you can. With concepts or SFINAE. See HolyBlackCat's answer.

Comment: _"or should I just let it throw an error"_ Prior to concepts, that is preferable (it would only throw an error anyway! Just... a nicer error...).

Comment: Prefer `const auto&` in the loop to avoid a copy here.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yes, ty

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have access to C++20, this is how you restrict the types your template accepts using concepts:

```
template <typename T>
concept printable = requires(T t)
{
    std::cout << t;
};

template <std::ranges::range T>
requires printable<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>
void print_iter(const T &iterable)
{
    for (const auto &it : iterable)
        std::cout << it << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

`concept printable = ...` defineds `printable` as a concept (a set of requirements for (usually) a type). This concept is satisfied when expression `std::cout << t` is well-formed, assuming `t` is a variable of type `T`.

In definition of `print_iter()`:

- `template <std::ranges::range T>` is same as `template <typename T>`, except it constrains the type with the concept `std::ranges::range` (which is what you called "iterable").
- `requires printable<std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>` adds an additional constraint to `T`: it requires that the type `std::ranges::range_value_t<T>` (the type of elements of `T`) satisfies our concepts `printable`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't have access to C++20, but when I do this is exactly what I will do. I'm not quite familiar with the decorum of stackoverflow yet, should I mark this answer as solution or bolov's answer? This is closer to what I want but bolov's answer is more immediately applicable to my needs.

Comment: @Peter the accept mark is yours to give to whomever you feel solved your issue. Don't sweat it. As long as you accept an answer all is well.

Comment: @Peter an answer being accepted is a good hint to the future reader, but it is not rare that the accepted isn't the best, so anyhow one has to read more than only that. Also having more than one complementary answers is common

Comment: In C++20, do concepts just allow for far better error messages?

Comment: @Eljay Better error messages (but not always), easier syntax (try writing this pre-C++20), and the fact that that concepts are partially ordered relative to each other, which opens new possibilities for function overloading.

Answer (score -5):

If you don't want to use C++20 concepts (or Rust traits), and you still want your function to only apply to iterable types (because nobody likes SFINAE errors), a technique is to require it to have a const_iterator:

```
template <typename T>
void print_range(const T& iterable, typename T::const_iterator = T{}.cbegin()) {
    for (const auto& elem : iterable) {
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In this case, the const_iterator argument had to be a defaulted dummy.
I previously suggested taking two iterators, but that required the caller to be explicit about the template type, which wasn't so cool.

A fair critique of the choice of const_iterator/cbegin as the defining characteristic of an iterable (not of this technique in general) is that not all iterable things have this interface. But this is not a real hindrance, as the caller can wrap it in a type with this interface. For example string_view in the case of C strings.

Comment: `T` can never be deduced

Comment: You should probably do `T begin, T end` to allow `T` to be deduced.

Comment: make it `template <typename Iterator>` and your example is fine

Comment: its not clear why you want to stay with `T` being the container type when anyhow it cannot be deduced. Whats the use of `T` in your code?   (you are not actually using it and instead you could parametrize on the iterator type)

Comment: Besiders, not all iterators are members of some container. Examples are pointers and things like `std::istream_iterator`.